# Dos elementos alinearlos verticalmente

Tags: css

Quiero ponerlo uno debajo del otro pero no funciona

```css
#tabla{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<nav style="float:left">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked span2">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div id="tabla" style="float:left"></div>
```

Comment: Yo solo veo un div.  Que es lo que quieres alinear?

Comment: el nav + el div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si remueves el `float: left` funciona:

```css
#tabla{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked span2">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div id="tabla" style="float:left"></div>
```